# Get overflow height with js

Tags: javascript, css

when you have a div with overflow: hidden and a longer div/element/image behind it, is it possible to get the length of the hidden element that is left at the bottom? For instance in the following image the dotted line is the hight value I need. Because this image scrolls, I need to know how much more I can scroll up.

because there is a changing height to the top of the overflow I cant just subtract the size visible by the images height.

[image]

Comment: You need to know total height of the semi-hidden content container, height of the screen, and the offset of the content container. All these can be taken from current styling of the elements and then you can easily calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it using .scrollHeight:

```
$('#myDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for responding. using scrollHeight was my first thought too. But it seems to only return the full height of the image. I just need the bottom overflow. Also due to the way its laid out (two divs and the scroll is actually a translate3d) I don't think that method would work. Thanks though!